# How to join these two mysql tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

Can someone help me with this query.

table **users**

```
+------+---------------------+  
| id   | name                |  
+------+---------------------+  
| 1    | John                |  
| 2    | Jade                |    
| 3    | Robbert             |  
| 4    | Steve               |
+------+---------------------+
```

table **friendship**

```
+------+---------------------+  
| uid  | friend_id           |  
+------+---------------------+  
| 1    | 2                   |  
| 1    | 3                   |    
| 2    | 4                   |  
+------+---------------------+
```

1. Assume current user id is 1.
2. **Want to get the name of current user friends.** ( all of them )
3. But this code returns only **current user name** for each friend it finds.

which for above example data, output is : `John` , `John` each one for each row.

```
$friends = DB::table('users')
->join('friendship', function($join)
{
    $join->on('users.id', '=', 'friendship.uid');
})
->where('friendship.blocked', '=', '0' )
->where('users.id', '=', '1' )
->get();
```

**Above SQL Code:**

```
select * from `users`
    inner join `friendship` 
        on `users`.`id` = `friendship`.`uid` 
where `users`.`id` = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your `join` condition. You're joining on the user id and you want to join on the friend side:

```
select name from users
join friendship on users.id = friendship.friend_id 
where friendship.uid = 1
```

In short, you're getting 2 `jhon` because you have 2 friends of `jhon` but you're getting the userid info of those pieces of data and you want the friend side.

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c272/1).

Comment: still getting `John` twice. current name. Note: This is laravel 4 syntax. it uses `inner join` instead of `join`. I don't know the difference.

Comment: It works fine. I've just added a fiddle proving so. Btw, `inner join` and `join` is the same for MySQL.

Comment: wow, very thank you. you saved my time. it's working... a typo from my part. after reading your query. i fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Might not be an exact answer to your question, but you should use Eloquent ORM to do things that simple, and it can be something liket this:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function friends()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('friendship', 'uid');
    }

} 

class Friendship extends Eloquent {

    public function user($query)
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'friend_id');
    }

    public function scopeBlocked($query)
    {
        return $query->where('blocked', '=', '0');
    }

    public function scopeNotBlocked($query)
    {
        return $query->where('blocked', '=', '1');
    }

}
```

Then you just have to use it:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$friends = $user->friends()->notBlocked()->get();

foreach($friends as $friend)
{
    echo $friend->user->name;
}
```

Comment: as far as I know ORM selects all columns and that is not good. ( select * ). I just want to get some specific columns.

Comment: You can use `get(['column1', 'column2'])` on Laravel Eloquent ORM. It will write `select column1, column2 ...`